# What Happens to the Boundary at Infinity of a CAT(0) Manifold if I Replace the R-Metric with Another with the Same Levi-Civita Connection?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

What happens to the boundary at infinity of a CAT(0) manifold if I replace the Riemannian metric with another one that has the same Levi-Civita connection? How do other CAT(0) invariants change?

So, the geodesics as paths remain invariant under such a change, but we are generally only interested in the unit-speed geodesics in CAT(0) geometry, and these **do** change nominally.

Has this question been asked before?

Comment: https://dilbert.com/strip/1992-04-09

Answer (score 1):

Per [this MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132244/can-one-recover-a-metric-from-geodesics/357025#357025), if $M$ is (connected and) irreducible, then any two Riemannian metrics inducing the same Levi-Civita connection differ by a scalar multiple, that is, if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are Riemannian metrics both inducing the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$, then there exists $c \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$ with $g_1 = cg_2$.

Hence, (if $M$ is connected and irreducible) the two visual boundaries should be the same. $\blacksquare$